# Building PCL on OSX 10.9

Tags: pcl, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing OSX 10.9, PCL does not build anymore. There were a few compilation and linking problems related to VTK 6.0, that I resolved somehow see [this discussion](http://answers.ros.org/question/93886/building-ros-on-osx-109-orocos_kdl/).
Now there is a compilation error

```
[ 21%] Building CXX object filters/CMakeFiles/pcl_filters.dir/src/extract_indices.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/user/Documents/temp/pcl/pcl/filters/src/extract_indices.cpp:41:
In file included from /Users/user/Documents/temp/pcl/pcl/filters/include/pcl/filters/impl/extract_indices.hpp:43:
In file included from /Users/user/Documents/temp/pcl/pcl/filters/include/pcl/filters/extract_indices.h:43:
In file included from /Users/user/Documents/temp/pcl/pcl/filters/include/pcl/filters/filter_indices.h:43:
In file included from /Users/user/Documents/temp/pcl/pcl/filters/include/pcl/filters/filter.h:43:
In file included from /Users/user/Documents/temp/pcl/pcl/common/include/pcl/pcl_base.h:45:
In file included from /Users/user/Documents/temp/pcl/pcl/common/include/pcl/pcl_macros.h:69:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/string:434:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:1795:32: error: cannot convert 'const pcl::Boundary' to
      'unsigned char' without a conversion operator
        _VSTD::memset(__first, (unsigned char)__value_, (size_t)(__n));
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94266/building-pcl-on-osx-10.9/) by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 709 on 2013-10-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-10-26**:
I also tried to compile the latest version of https://github.com/kylelutz/pcl.git and with the vtk6-fixes branch, but then I get some eigen error ...

**Comment by [Ivano](https://answers.ros.org/users/8156/ivano/) on 2013-10-26**:
The eigen issue has been solved here https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/283
Regarding the rest, I'm getting the same errors as yourself above after upgrading to Mavericks. V frustrating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By adding the two following lines in the file CMakeLists.txt

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ftemplate-depth=1024")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libstdc++")

under

string(TOLOWER ${PROJECT_NAME} PROJECT_NAME_LOWER)

I've managed to get PCL 1.7.1 built succesfully on OS 10.9. That should also work for the trunk.

It seems that these kind of issues boil down to the swap of defaults libstdc++ / libc++ in Xcode 5.0.1

---

Originally posted by [Ivano](https://answers.ros.org/users/8156/ivano/) with karma: 36 on 2013-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-10-26**:
Thanks Ivano! It did help to pass those errors. I got stuck with linking errors.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"vtkObjectBase::PrintHeader(std::ostream&, vtkIndent)", referenced from:
vtable for pcl::visualization::PointPickingCallback in point_picking_event.cpp.o
vtable for pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle in interactor_style.cpp.o
...

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-10-26**:
What version of VTK did you install?

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-10-26**:
Adding -DBUILD_visualization=off allowed me successfuly built PCL. Did you have to turn visualisation off too?

**Comment by [Ivano](https://answers.ros.org/users/8156/ivano/) on 2013-10-27**:
Awesome. No, I didn't need the VTK I'm afraid. Anyway here (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) you can find the new CUDA library for OS X 10.9 rolled out from NVIDIA just last night.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-10-27**:
Just a small side question, did you manage to install qt? It doesnt compile for me.

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-10-27**:
Nope, here is a discussion on this issue https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/21000

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-10-28**:
I managed to compile Qt, using the patches from here: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,69325

**Comment by [Ivano](https://answers.ros.org/users/8156/ivano/) on 2013-10-28**:
Cool. Thanks!